# How to cumulate property placeholder?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

We have a classic Maven, Spring (3.1.1) application where we created an applicationContext.xml.

In this file, we have declared a property placeholder with an external file and a file in classpath.
Here an example found in another question here :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${ADMIN_HOME}/db.properties,classpath:configuration.properties"
ignore-unresolvable="false" ignore-resource-not-found="false" />
```

It is working.

But now, we have a specific config file for JUnit tests.
In this config file, we have imported the first one and added a property placeholder for tests with a classic declaration.

```
<import resource="applicationContext.xml" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:configuration-test.properties"
    ignore-unresolvable="false" ignore-resource-not-found="false" />
```

We have injected a value from configuration-test.properties in JUnit test.

```
@Value("${junit.user.login}")
private String login;
```

But when we launch the JUnit, an error is raised.
The key "junit.user.login" is not resolved.

We don't know why.
Any idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Is your junit launching the correct spring context?
You added the correct xml paths to the test case like so?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/my-test-context.xml" })
public class TestCase{}
```

Comment: Yes. @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext-test.xml")
public class DocumentServiceTest {}

Comment: We didn't have a problem before to add the external file in main config file. All tests were working until we have this new feature. It is the fact to add "file:${ADMIN_HOME}/db.properties" which create a regression.

Comment: In that case I think the issue is with the ${ADMIN_HOME} which is not known to spring when running a test. Maybe try to launch the test with additional -DADMIN_HOME=<path>

Comment: No pb with $ADMIN_HOME. All properties are loaded. The pb is for config test file. I succeed to execute my test if i set ignore-unresolvable = true in my applicationContext-test.xml. But i don't understand why, and if it is the good thing to do.